# Bootstrap 3 Popover with function for content

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Bootstrap 3 provides a [Popover](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) that I'm trying to use. The [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-options) say that the `data-content` may be either a string or a function. However, I seem unable to set the content to a function:

```
<button type="button" 
        class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" 
        data-toggle="popover" 
        title="Popover title" 
        data-content="my_function();">
  Click to toggle popover
</button>
```

And here's the JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})

function my_function(){
    return "This is my popover's content";
}
```

You can try the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/heb6gt6p/).

I've also tried variations like `data-content="javascript:my_function();"`. I'm not sure if my syntax is just a little off, or if you can't use `data-content` this way.

Is it possible to specify a function for a Popover's content using the `data-content` attribute? Or am I misunderstanding the docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to specify a function for a Popover's content using the `data-content` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the `data-`, (i.e., data-content) attribute through `$(elem).popover(options)`

```
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    content: my_function(this)
  })
```

Here's your revised fiddle for you to review. https://jsfiddle.net/heb6gt6p/1/

Comment: Thanks Chris- I am aware that I can set it via JavaScript, but I am particularly wondering if it can be done using the `data-content` attribute on the element itself.

Comment: Nope, because it will assume it as a string. As you already found out.